# jQuery does not find IMG component by its ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage which contains such code:

```
<img class="img-qrcode" id="img_123.000.00.01" 
     src="http://localhost:7777/data/code_img\123.000.00.01.png" 
     alt="./data/code_img\123.000.00.01.png" style="display:none">
```

I want to locate it with jQuery. For some reason jQuery does not find it by ID, with the code:

```
$("#img_123.000.00.01")
```

The added screenshot shows that it returns an empty array.

[image: The img with this ID exists but jquery does not see it]

Why does it not find the element with ID ?

Comment: Because it's not **valid** , Is `img-qrcode` an unique class?

Comment: You should escape the dots. https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I get values of IDs from database, the HTML page is formed by PHP script. These IDs mean the codes of parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for `id`, you don't have to worry about escaping the class selector (`.`)

```js
let img = $("img[id='img_123.000.00.01']");
console.log(img.attr('src'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="img-qrcode" id="img_123.000.00.01" 
     src="http://localhost:7777/data/code_img\123.000.00.01.png" 
     alt="./data/code_img\123.000.00.01.png" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 1):

The a `.` character has special meaning in a selector (it starts a class selector) so you need to escape it.  (Remember to escape the slash character in a string literal).

Generally it is easier to just avoid using `.` chapters in an id.

Comment: I cannot avoid '.' symbols, because they are unique identifiers entered by users... They are IDs of parts.

Comment: @IvanP. — Then either (1) When prompting users to enter a unique ID, ban `.` or (2) **Do what I said in the first paragraph**.

Answer (score 0):

Find with `^`

```js
let img = $("img[id^='img_123']");
console.log(img.attr('src'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="img-qrcode" id="img_123" 
     src="http://localhost:7777/data/code_img\123.000.00.01.png" 
     alt="./data/code_img\123.000.00.01.png" style="display:none">
```

Comment: Does not fit my specifics. I may have ID which looks like '799.00.000.01'

Comment: @IvanP. It's totally wrong and invalid! can not start an `id` with number!

Answer (score 0):

Since `#id.className` is a valid selector jQuery assumes it so and tries to find such element. In your case you will have to escape the dot.

Change `$("#img_123.000.00.01")` to `$("#img_123\\.000\\.00\\.01")` and it will work.

Official jQuery documentation(https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) states it clearly.

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, it
>   must be escaped with with two backslashes

Comment: This return undefined, try to test it before post it

Comment: I have tested it and it does not return undefined. You can check it here: https://codepen.io/v08i/pen/mdJPjWx  Console output here: https://i.imgur.com/cKXJJ1M.png

Answer (score 0):

When some special symbols are in the jquery selector, you need to add 『\\』

```js
console.log($("#img_123\\.000\\.00\\.01"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <img class="img-qrcode" id="img_123.000.00.01" src="http://localhost:7777/data/code_img\123.000.00.01.png" alt="./data/code_img\123.000.00.01.png" style="display:none">
</body>

</html>
```